# how to different :focus on click VS on tab?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to trigger visual effect only when the user click TAB and focus element. not when he's using his mouse.

There is any way of doing it with the boundaries of CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? The element ends up in the same state either way.

Comment: have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: when the user click TAB? no ways by css, but there is by js